# 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 3: invalid continuation byte on Jinja2 template

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

I'm trying to parse a string value in a jinja template, but I'm getting this error:

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# encoding: utf-8
...
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
...
data_html_template = j2_env.get_template(data_html_template_file).render(
          ...      
          breakdown=str(breakdown)
         ...
          )

...
```

breakdown is the variable with special characters.

How can I fix this?

This is my full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/scripts/planning/noc/api/send_outliers_emails.py", line 122, in <module>
    deviate_perc=int(100*row['gmv_deviate_from_expected']/row['gmv_expected'])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/var/scripts/planning/noc/email_templates/breakdown_data_template.html", line 9, in top-level template code
    <td align="center" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: #eee; border-bottom-style: solid; margin: 0;padding: 3px 0 0 0;">{{deviate_perc}}%</td>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

I'm getting the data from SQL Alchemy, this is how I'm getting it and passing it to a pandas data frame:

```
SQL_ENGINE = '{db}://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}'.format(
      db=db,
      db_user=db_user,
      db_password=db_password,
      db_host=db_host,
      db_port=db_port,
      db_name=db_name
    )
    engine = create_engine(SQL_ENGINE,encoding='utf8', convert_unicode=True)
    data_frame = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
```

Comment: usually it means that incoming string is in different encoding, let's say latin-1. However, I would be happy to see the troubleshooting plan as well.

Comment: Please don't use the `setdefaultencoding()` hack. You are just plastering over the real issues. Please include a full traceback of your exception, not just the exception message.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I added the full error.

Comment: So what data are you passing in there? Are there any bytestrings in there with non-ASCII data? One of those is currently being decoded (implicitly) to Unicode, and your `setdefaultencoding()` call means that Python will use UTF-8 to decode with. That fails for a bytestring you have passed into the template.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The string is 'Óculos' that is causing trouble

Comment: You're trying to encode / decode strings, not Unicode strings. The following statements do work: `u'ç'.encode('utf8')` or `u'á'.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, this is i the string. I added how I'm getting the data at the question end. I'm getting it from a Mysql, with sql alchemy and passing to a pandas data frame. Hope this helps you help me.

Comment: @VladyslavUshakov they are not trying to encode. The error shows there is an implicit decode.

Comment: @FilipeFerminiano what does `print(repr(string))` look like? It looks to me you have Latin-1 byte data. I'm not familiar with how pandas and MySQL interact.

Comment: You'd normally pass in Unicode strings. It is technically possible for MySQL to give you Unicode strings rather than byte data but with Pandas in the mix I don't know how that works. If you can at least provide an [mcve] that reproduces the data you pass into Jinja we can possibly help.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for pointing the latin1 encoding. I transformed the string from latin1 to utf8 and it's working now.